# How to assign text to the controller when creating a Textfield dynamically?

Tags: flutter

I have to create `TextField` widgets dynamically. I'm using the following widget..

```
class DynamicTextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Response response;

  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  DynamicTextFieldWidget({this.controller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'hint Text '),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a `ListView.builder` where I need to assign text to the controller (Response object contains a `List<Content>`) and the content object has a property body(String) that I need to assign as text to the controller of the textfield. Here is what I have..

```
Widget responseContent(Response response) {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: response.content.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, item) {
        return Column(
//Need to assign content[item].body to DynamicTextFieldWidget()
          children: [DynamicTextFieldWidget(), Image.network(response.content[item].media.url)],
        );
      });
}
```

Nor sure hoe to assign the text to the controller...

Comment: assign text to the controller ? mean as a value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this

1. you could create a controller dynamically while the listview builds and pass in the controller

```
Widget responseContent(Response response) {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: response.content.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, item) {
      final initialText = response.content[item].body;
      final textEditingController = TextEditingController(text:initialText);
        return Column(
          children: [
            DynamicTextFieldWidget(controller:textEditingController), 
            Image.network(response.content[item].media.url)],
        );
      });
}
```

2. You have to make your DynamicTextField Stateful and you could pass your initial value in the constructor and assign it to textfield in initState

Pass the desired value in the DynamicTextFieldWidget()

```
 final initialText = response.content[item].body;
return Column(
          children: [
            DynamicTextFieldWidget(initialText:initialText), 
            Image.network(response.content[item].media.url)],
        );
```

Assign the value in initState

```
class DynamicTextFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initialText;
  
  DynamicTextFieldWidget(this.initialText);
  
  @override
  _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState createState() => _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState();
}

class _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState extends State<DynamicTextFieldWidget> {


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText);
  }

...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Your DynamicTextFieldWidget to this :

```
class DynamicTextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Response response;

  final TextEditingController _controller;
  DynamicTextFieldWidget(this._controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'hint Text '),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the later part like this

```
Widget responseContent(Response response) {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: response.content.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, item) {
        return Column(
//Need to assign content[item].body to DynamicTextFieldWidget()
          children: [DynamicTextFieldWidget(TextEditingController(text:response.content[item].body), Image.network(response.content[item].media.url)],
        );
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your DynamicTextField stateful widget and do the following :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynamicTextFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initialData;
  
  DynamicTextFieldWidget(this.initialData);
  
  @override
  _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState createState() => _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState();
}

class _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState extends State<DynamicTextFieldWidget> {
  String initialData = '';

  TextEditingController controller;
  _DynamicTextFieldWidgetState({this.controller});

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialData = widget.initialData;
    controller = TextEditingController(text: initialData);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'hint Text '),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To use multiple DynamicTextFieldWidget inside a listview do the following:

```
Widget responseContent(Response response) {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: response.content.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, item) {
        return Column(
          children: [DynamicTextFieldWidget(key:UniqueKey(),response.content[item].body)],
        );
      });
}
```

Note: here you need to provide UniqueKey in order to uniquely indentify each of the edittext separately.